# Generating points around straight line

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-generation

I'm doing some clustering research and need to generate synthetic data that would look something like these examples:

[image: Dataset examples]

We have 2d plots with 2 classes (red and black). How could I generate 2D data like this? It has a V structure, so I was thinking about generating points around straight lines - is there a way to do that in **R**?
I'm using **R**, but am open to other tools (just data has to be exportable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a thought.

```
n <- c(200,200)                 # Number of points in each class
cls <- rep(1:2, n)              # Class memberships
i <- c(.2-.12*abs(rnorm(n[1])), # Noiseless x position
       -.2+.12*abs(rnorm(n[2])))
noise <- .04*(.2-abs(i))        # Noise level relative to `i`

# Final sample
x <- cbind(i, abs(.5*i)) + noise*matrix(rnorm(sum(n)*2), sum(n), 2)

plot(x[,1], x[,2], col=cls)
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! I was working on a density estimator once and had to generate all kinds of crazy distributions to benchmark on, it's quite fun.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason to generate this *very particular* type of data? Any results drawn from this will likely not generalize to other datasets.

Anyway, the obvious way to generate this kind of data is to use a nonlinear projection, e.g. using the famous "abs" function (absolute value).

i.e. project x to (in python syntax, I don't like R): `math.abs(x)` or if you want some extra randomness: `math.abs(x + random.random(.1)) + random.random(.1)`

Comment: In R: `abs(x + rnorm(length(x), sd = .1)) + rnorm(length(x), sd = .1)`, with runif instead of rnorm if that's your type of noise :)

Comment: Actually I'm testing my similarity measure on 'Congressional Voting Records Data Set': archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Congressional+Voting+Records
If I scale (cmdscale) generated distance matrix to 2 dimensions I get points as in examples above. My similarity measure has one parameter and with voting dataset I get different results for different values of that parameter. I wanted to see if this is true for all clusters with similar shape.

Comment: I'm not sure how sensible `cmdscale` is on a dataset consisting of binary vectors. This can produce odd projections. You really should inspect the type of projection produced by `cmdscale`, which could boil down to something like "number of `y` on bills" and the voting behavior on a particular bill. So it could be that what you are seeing is an *artifact* of your preprocessing applied to binary data vectors.

Comment: For data generation, it may then work very well for you to generate binary vectors first (for probability p, class 1 votes "y" with `p` and "n" with 1-p, while class 2 does the inverse), then project them via `cmdscale`.